# Trouble while trying to re-run open source code

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, series-expansion, recursion

I am a physics student and this is my first time working with Mathematica. I am trying to run the notebook mentioned [here](https://centra.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/network/grit/files/amplification-factors/), titled "Amplification factors of the superradiant scattering of a charged wave off a
spherically-symmetric or a slowly-rotating BH with generic metric" by Cardoso, Pani and Brito.

Essentially, I am trying to numerically integrate a differential equation. The section I am having trouble with is the following:

```
ORDH = 3;
h[r_] := Sum[hh[i] (r - rp)^i, {i, 0, ORDH}]
ruleH = {};
ss = Series[eqSH //. ruleH, {r, rp, ORDH}];
eqsH = Table[SeriesCoefficient[ss, i] == 0, {i, 1, ORDH}]
yh = Table[hh[i], {i, 1, ORDH}]
Length[eqsH]
Length[yh]
seriesH = Solve[eqsH, yh][[1]] // Simplify;
seriesH = Union[seriesH, ruleH]
Clear[h]
```

`eqsH` is the expression for a homogenous differential equation in terms of `h[r]` and it's derivatives. From my understanding, what they are trying to do here, is to expand `h[r]` as a series about the point `rp` (which is also defined as a constant value earlier in the program) upto 3rd order. Then `eqsH` is redefined as a table involving each coefficient of the first to third powers of `(r-rp)` set individually to zero. `yh` is just a list containing these coefficients. Since these two lists together make up a linear system of equations in terms of the variables `hh[i]` this can be solved using the `Solve` command.

When I run this program it runs until I get the Length of both lists (I get 3 as the output as required). When it begins to solve the equations, it runs indefinitely. In a friend's computer, it took about a minute to run (his computer does have better performance, but my PC ranks quite well in Mathematica's internal benchmarking test). When I try to abort the evaluation I get the following errors:

```
$RecursionLimit:Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of Union[seriesH,{}]
```

and

```
Union: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Union[seriesH,{}]
```

Regarding the recursion limit I have tried to reset it as follows:

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 10000}, seriesH]
```

But this changes nothing. I do not understand the other error. How do I resolve this?

Comment: You should copy and paste every line. Second line `eqSH = eqS /. k -> -kH; `is missing

Comment: Yes. That is a constant replacement. I linked the whole notebook because I felt like my post was already too long. While running it, I am running it in order.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Can you mention which version of Mathematica you're running and which OS?  And which version & OS your friend is using?  I'm suspicious is that this is due to a change in how Mathematica behaves between versions.

Comment: I am running Mathematica 12.3.1 on Windows 10. My friend is running Mathematica 12.1.1 on an M1 MacBook Air.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are receiving are because you are aborting the code.  If you run the penultimate line of the code,

```
seriesH = Union[seriesH, ruleH]
```

on a "clean" kernel (with nothing in memory), you get exactly the same errors.  This suggests that the errors arise because you aborting the code before the previous line defines `seriesH`.

As to why it is taking so long on your machine, I'm not sure.  I'll note that even if you set `ORDH` to 1, the `Solve` command still seems to take an inordinately long time despite the fact that you're asking it to solve an equation of the form `A hh[0] + B hh[1] == 0` for `hh[1]`.  One would think this would be nearly instantaneous, yet here we are.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you suggesting that the recursion depth error is also because I am aborting the code? 
And regarding the time, does it seem to universally take that long? I have already tried it on two different computers, and it seems to be really slow on all the Windows machines I've tried.

Comment: @newtothis:  Yes, the recursion depth error is due to aborting the code;  I suspect it is unrelated to the slowness of the equation-solving.  You could test this by quitting your kernel and then running the code `seriesH = {foo};  seriesH = Union[seriesH, ruleH]`.  If I'm right, then it should return `{foo}` without errors.  (I'd try it myself, but I can't run Mathematica right now.)

Comment: As far as the amount of time the `Solve` command takes, I really don't know what's going on there.  I ran the code with `ORDH = 1` for over an hour on a year-old MacBook Pro and it did not complete.

Comment: Yeah it returns ``{foo}`` but this also takes a very long time. If I abort it, it returns ``{foo}``. I have even tried reinstalling Mathematica, and running this file on WolframCloud. It's the same issue on Wolfram Cloud as well.

Comment: So I installed Mathematica 12.0 instead of 12.3 and now, the code runs and completes in around 5 minutes. So I think that solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Weird.  I wouldn't expect such a big slow-down on a later version.  It might be worth contacting Wolfram Support and seeing if they have any clues as to why the performance is worse in a newer version.  If I had to guess, I would wager that the `$Assumptions` might be handled differently in the newer version and that's what's causing the slow-down.